# Hide result List of jquery Autocomplete

Tags: jquery-ui, autocomplete, response

I am using the jQuery UI autocomplete functionality searching and returning some values via ajax. Currently I am using it like this:

```
            $(".myautocomplete").autocomplete(
            {
                source: "myajaxSourceAsJson",
                minLength: 1,
                delay: 500,
                response: function( event, ui ) {
                    // Do something with the response data
                }

            });
```

My JSON-Object not only contains "value" and "label", but also some more objects, which I am using in the response of the autocomplete. Now I still see the autocomplete-list below the html input field, which I'd simply like to hide, because I don't it in this case. I know I also could create the same same functionality with a "normal" ajax-request and the key-events, but I need the minlength and delay-functionality of the autocomplete. Is there a possibility of hiding the list of results below the input field? I tried with "display:none;" for some of the autocomplete classes, but it quite likely is overwritten by the autocomplete itself.

I also tried

.ui-autocomplete { height: 0px; overflow-y: scroll; overflow-x: hidden;}

But then there is a small area of white pixels visible every time someone triggers a search inside the field.

Answer (score 0):

> Now I still see the autocomplete-list below the html input field,
>   which I'd simply like to hide, because I don't it in this case.

I'm not sure if I fully understand your question... Why would you want auto-complete functionality if you just want to hide it?

But I can recommend using an anonymous function to create the data for your auto-complete..

```
$(".myautocomplete").autocomplete(
            {
                source: function(request, response){ 
                // do some data manipulation here... 
                // perhaps return an empty list...
                },
                minLength: 1,
                delay: 500,
                response: function( event, ui ) {
                    // Do something with the response data
                }

            });
```